# How to GET and parse data from website? Unity3D

Tags: http, user-interface, unity-game-engine, get, web

I am new at this and I do not know how to get info from site and show it in UI. I have tried using plugins but do not know how to. I want to get the numbers showing on the site which are constantly updated to be shown in a UI field when refresh button is click. Can someone please help I am stuck over here. 
The site is results site which revise the numbers on it daily bases. The numbers are changing and its a active server page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vancete said, WWW could be used to solve this.

Create a Coroutine, load the data from the webpage and then do something with it.

```
IEnumerator GetDataFromWebpage (string url)
{
    WWW webpage = new WWW(url);
    while (!webpage.isDone) yield return false;
    string content = webpage.text;
    . . .
    // Do something with <content>
}
```

Comment: I think Ron wants to render the webpage as a texture in 3d space. I don't believe just getting html is going to help.

Comment: @Brandon.Blanchard Huh I just realised that you are right ... my bad, sorry.

Comment: I do that ALL.THE.TIME. context is hard.

Comment: the problem is the numbers updating is all I want .. if I do the webpage as 3d texture it gets the whole site.. I also tried getting both by the http client plugin in unity store but can't get it done can you help in this..

Comment: @Ron can you update your question and explain what website you're trying to get numbers from and what numbers you're after?

Comment: @Brandon.Blanchard the site is a result page where the results are updated daily. I want to get the displayed result number to UI text field in unity

Comment: @IanH. is it on the asset store

Comment: @Ron It is not only for unity, rather a general helper for C#. Get it [here](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

So you should create an WWW object with the desired URL, wait for the response, then load the object.text property. After all, do a substring of what you need and you are done!

Feel free to ask if you need some more help.

Comment: You don't need a plugin to do of any of these. Linking one is totally unnecessary.

Comment: I know its a bit of a stretch but can you give an example, perhaps a tutorial or steps to how to do this. I am a newbie at this and want to understand it well

Comment: @Programmer just curious how linking to the official documentation is a plugin ?